# Variable in YAML file to put it as tag in cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I want to deploy and EC2, where as tag I desire to put datetime as key value. How do I manipulate  and pass on the key value in Tag?

Any help on it would be appreciated.

Thanks.
AS

Answer (score 1):

You **can't get timestamp** directly in CFN. But you can design your own [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in CFN. The resource would be in the form of a **lambda function** which would use AWS API to add tags with timestamps to your resources.